# Calculating intracluster correlation coefficient for a continuous variable in R

Tags: r, correlation

How might I calculate intracluster correlation coefficient for continuous data in R?

I've found a couple of packages that calculate for binary data, but not continuous.

I've been looking at [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#Modern_ICC_definitions:_simpler_formula_but_positive_bias), but am not entirely clear on precisely how to calculate between and within cluster variance.

I would like to calculate for data that are essentially like this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
n = 100
data.dt = data.table(cluster = sample(c(1,2,3), n, replace = T))
data.dt[,outcome := rnorm(n, mean = cluster, sd = 1)]
data.dt[,cluster := factor(cluster)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use aov:

```
summary_aov = summary(aov(outcome ~ cluster,data=data.dt))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
cluster      2 67.436  33.718  38.286 5.543e-13 ***
Residuals   97 85.427   0.881
```

under the column Sum Sq you have the first term as between group (or cluster) variance and the second term as within group variance.

Then the ICC you are interested in:

```
summary_aov[[1]][1,2]/sum(summary_aov[[1]][,2])
0.4411529
```

Note that the link you posted, it's for a mixed effect model which has random effects that are not present in your example.

Comment: Thanks! This might be a rookie question, but is the randomness imparted by rnorm in my example not a random effect?

Comment: Well random effect does not mean randomness. It refers to effects which you want to adjust for in a linear model, but are not interested in testing, as opposed to fixed effects

Comment: In any case, if you are not using a mixed model, it does not affect you. You can still use the ICC as defined above.